How do anime productions get their backgrounds to have their textures?
I'm relatively new to graphic design but have noticed that more often than not in anime cartoons, the backgrounds will have an almost pastel-ish, watercolor-esque background that makes it appears as if the layers are textures.
Is this done by using a filter or a blur or does the artist use custom brushes in Photoshop to achieve that?



It is impossible to know how some artists do something unless you ask them or find a tutorial or timelapse he/she made.
If the question is more specific:
Can you enlist some methods to add texture to an illustration, specifically a watercolor look?
Then yes, you can:

Add a filter. Watercolor is a bit complex, but I personally find this specific filter quite good. https://www.filterforge.com/filters/7227.html

Or find some other option: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=watercolor+filter

Digitally paint it. The two software that IMHO are the best for watercolor, Corel Painter www.painterartist.com and Rebelle www.escapemotions.com/products/rebelle Rebelle even have an online canvas you can play with. But there are a lot of them. Google diferent options.

Paint it on paper and scan it.

Find some AI software to add the watercolor style.

Find some other software that makes textures. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Paint+filter+for+photos



I would say that the style you posted could also be some acrylic paint style, but you got the idea.
There are some other methods to add texture. Adding noise, merging textures using different opacities and blending modes, etc.
